stylistic usage replacing conjunctions with commas

She was bright and beautiful, not offended by her detractors. (and)

She was attractive, some say beautiful.


Would the dropping of conjunction (and)** be stylistic choice**, and 2 despite requiring a semi-colon may stylistically look alright with a comma?

None of these seem very natural to me; mispunctuated at the very least (the punctuation is probably OK in very informal contexts). Where are they from? Did you read them somewhere or make them up yourself? 1 is probably grammatically OK, since it's just omitting a repetition of "(and) she was", but there doesn't seem to be a clear enough contrast to make "not" fit there. 3 arguably needs a semicolon, although again "she was" can be omitted; 2 and 4 really need "with".


Without 'and', it's a participial phrase: not (being) offended. It's grammatical. 2. It is 'with participial phrase': with more grain and digital noise reduction (being) present. you need 'with' as Stuart F said. 3. You need 'but' or 'though;'. Two sentences need conjunction to be grammatical. 4. You need 'due to' or 'because of' to be grammatical. The 'some' in 3 is a subject as well as pronoun and as well as some people. The 'some' in 4 is an adjective modifying 'signs'.


It's impossinble to answer because the structures are all different.

It was  some being used as a noun that I did not instantly notice - sort of answered what I was confused about. Some (People) versus some other (time).
